# Remove "Filter" Button on All Posts in wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin

I've used code to remove other elements on the bar where the "Filter" button is displayed, but I can't find a way to (ideally) disable or (less ideally) hide this button.

[image]

Comment: You can hide it visually via CSS, e.g. `#posts-filter .tablenav .actions { display: none; }`, or use JS to remove the "actions" div or just that button. But are you sure you want to disable the ability to filter the posts via that div/button?

Comment: Looking at the wordpress repo there doesn't seem to be an easy way to remove that button without editing core files, no action/filter is available for you to hook into. Seems like the best way woulf be with css, as @SallyCJ suggested.

Comment: @SallyCJ yes, actually I want to understand how it works on Posts first and then do it on a custom post type that has no need for such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a filter or an action in order to prevent this BUT

Wordpress adds the post-type slug of the current page post type to the classes in body tag. Also the slug of the page, in your case *.edit-php*

If you want to do it with css (replace {your_post_type} with your post type)

```
body.post-type-{your_post_type}.edit-php #post-query-submit{
    display: none!important;
}
```

ie: for *page* post type:

```
body.post-type-page.edit-php #post-query-submit{
    display: none!important;
}
```

If you want to do it in javascript:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', function(){
    echo <<<EOF
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('body.post-type-{your_post_type}.edit-php #post-query-submit').remove();
    });
</script>
EOF;

} );
```

Remember to replace {your_post_type} with the slug of your custom post type.